# Ask for really nasty PHP query (distinct dates from unixtime both in future and past)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 table (meetings) containing some occursion unix timestamps (dates), mostly upcoming meetings in future.
For example:

id.1 30-3-2011 (Wednesday) - future

id.2 31-3-2011 (Thursday). - future

On the other hand, there is 1 more table (schedule), containing unix timestamps also in column(dates) but - in past. In a difference to example above, these are sessions going on every Wednesday, or Tuesday, every week. Although dates are written in past, by using date_format (w), PHP collects them out by function date("w"), as "for today" whats not a problem.

ie.

id.44 15-3-2011 (Tuesday) - past (3 weeks ago!)

id.45 25-3-2011 (Friday) - past

Now, problem occurs to show them all joined as in future as "upcomings" by - distinct dates and days!

Today is Monday 28/3/2011 and output should look like this.

++Tuesday (29.3)
id.44

++ Wednesday (30.3) 
id.1

++ Thursday (31.3.) 
id.2

++ Friday (1.4.) 
id.45.

Really, any ideas? :)

Separated queries per distinct dates are also welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc, Skrol29, everyone thanx for effort. Unfortunately, those "past" meetings may contain dates way beyond in past (over 2 years sometimes) so hard coding will not do the job.

It seems this table requires special 24/7/30 algorithm/calendar, sort of converter before main query itself but its something I can do myself.

I just had a thought theres easier or practical solution, but seems not.

Answer (score 0):

How do you identifier the "past" events that re-occur and should show up on the future calendars?

I'll assume you've got a "repeat" flag on the event record, so something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM schedule
WHERE (eventdate BETWEEN now() and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
   OR ((repeat = 1) AND (eventdate < now())
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT date_format(from_unixtime(dates),'%w') as day FROM schedule


That does "the days", even joined, but I cant print those according to date in future. Btw its not a calendar, only a small archive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
("(SELECT DISTINCT date_format(from_unixtime(dates),'%w') as day 
FROM schedule)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT date_format(from_unixtime(dates),'%w') as day
FROM meetings"))
```

I guess im trying to create a calendar right now. Btw any thoughts how events can be printed out accordingly to date (with no time) like 30.3., 1.4. and so on for example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query for your result ('2011-03-28' is the date that you may replace by any one, your can replace it by a paremeter in your code ) :

```
SELECT id, DateX
FROM (

  SELECT m_id AS id, m_date AS DateX FROM meeting WHERE (m_date>='2011-03-28')

  UNION ALL

  SELECT s_id AS id ,
  ADDDATE(CONVERT('2011-03-28',DATE), INTERVAL MOD(7+DAYOFWEEK(s_date)-DAYOFWEEK('2011-03-28'),7) DAY ) AS DateX
  FROM schedule

) AS u
ORDER BY DateX
```

#### Explanations:

The final query is the union of two sub-queries.
The first one is simply the dates of meetings that will occur after the given date (2011-03-08).
The second query has a complicated expression, but its goal is to return all the dates in the schedule table, but with a shift of weeks that brings them immediately after the given date (2011-03-08).

The complicated formula with AddDate(), Mod() and DayOfWeek() is only adding to the given date (2011-03-08) the number of days that it's missing in order to reach the same day of week of the schedule date. The Mod() function is here only to ensure that this number of days is positive, otherwise it shifts it for one more week.

As you can see, the complete query will return the periodical Schedule dates for the next 7 days, but no more. There is an impossibility to return all the future periodical Schedule dates because they are infinite.

Regards,